# How to Display an output with a value 0

Tags: sql

I have a query where it returns the number of tickets resolved by a member. However, if a member has done 0 tickets he/she is not displayed in the output. Is there a way to let the query return that value to zero instead of removing it?

Example:

```
select loginname,
       count(id) as total_tickets
from tickets
where loginname in ("x", "y", "z", "s", "a")
```

Output was like this:

```
x      10
y      16
z      20
a      8
```

I know s has a value of 0 but I want to make it visible. Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Hi, what database do you use ?

Comment: As a menber without a ticket is not in the ticket table of course, you'd select the member from the members table. Then **outer join** the tickets table or a ticket query (the already aggregated tickets).

Comment: And you need to GROUP BY as well. Your current query is invalid and expected to raise an error.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3):

You didn't specify your DBMS, but in standard ANSI SQL, you can do an outer join against a list of values:

```
select v.name,
       count(t.id) as total_tickets
from (
  values ('x'), ('y'), ('z'), ('s'), ('a') 
) as v(name)  
  left join tickets t on t.loginname = v.name
group by v.name;
```

Note that string values need to be enclosed in single quotes in standard SQL (double quotes are for identifiers).

If your DBMS doesn't support the VALUES clause like that, you can e.g. use a `union` to build up the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is invalid. It is missing the `GROUP BY` clause. You are also using double quotes where it should be single quotes.

You are looking for an outer join. Select from members, join the tickets or ticket counts.

With a join before aggregation:

```
select
  m.loginname,
  count(id) as total_tickets
from members m
left outer join tickets t on t.loginname = m.loginname
where m.loginname in ('x', 'y', 'z', 's', 'a')
group by m.loginname
order by m.loginname;
```

With a join after aggregation (which I usually prefer):

```
select
  m.loginname,
  t.total_tickets
from members m
left outer join 
(
  select loginname, count(*) as total_tickets
  from tickets
  group by loginname
) t on t.loginname = m.loginname
where m.loginname in ('x', 'y', 'z', 's', 'a')
order by m.loginname;
```